# How to implement AuthorizationContext attribute on WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement password expiry policy and found a good [blog showing an example](https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/implement-password-expiration-check-in-asp-net-mvc/) - but that is in MVC. I'm trying to implement it for WebApi2. I expected WebApi to have similar functionality but so far have failed to locate the right namespaces / methods to call.

Relevant part of the code:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (!filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(SkipPasswordExpirationCheckAttribute), inherit: true)
        && !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(SkipPasswordExpirationCheckAttribute), inherit: true))
        {
            ...

            if (timeSpan.Days >= _maxPasswordAgeInDay)
            {
                ...

                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("ChangePassword", "Account", new { reason = "passwordExpired" }));
            }
        }

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

1. On WebApi, the override method signature is `OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)` instead of `(AuthorizationContext filterContext)` - how do I check for `SkipPasswordExpirationAttribute` using actionContext?
2. Once I decide the password has expired, what action should I take? I don't suppose I can "redirect" user from WebApi as that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ActionDescriptor` or `ControllerContext` properties to look for the attribute you want.

Here is an example of how to check for `SkipPasswordExpirationAttribute`.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
    var attribute = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SkipPasswordExpirationAttribute >(true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (attribute != null)
        return;
    //You have access to the Request and Response as well.
    var request = actionContext.Request;
    var response = actionContext.Response;

    //...Once you decide the password has expired, 
    //update the response with an appropriate status code 
    //and response message that would make sense 
    //to the client that made the request
    response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    response.ReasonPhrase = "Password expired";

    base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
}
```